# Typescript: function should return value of generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic function that takes a 'parser'-function as parameter:

```
async http<HTTPRESP, RETVAL>(
    request: RequestInfo,
    responseHandler: (resp: HTTPRESP) => RETVAL = (resp: HTTPRESP): RETVAL => ***  // <-- ?
): Promise<RETVAL> {

    const response: Response = await fetch(request);
    const result: HTTPRESP = await response.json() as HTTPRESP;
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(responseHandler(result)));

}
```

The return type of the 'parser'-function (here: responseHandler) is also the return type of 'http' function: RETVAL.

I want to give the 'parser'-function also a default value.
Here, RETVAL could be anything: any, void, string, number, Array, etc.

To make this work, what should be placed at '***'?

Comment: Nothing sound. Don't put default value there.

Comment: Dont put default value as @polkovnikov.ph said. Also you can cast return promise this way:
`return new Promise(resolve => resolve(responseHandler(result))) as unknown as Promise<RETVAL>;`

Comment: "as unknown as Promise<RETVAL>;" this solved it, thanks!

Comment: Note that `new Promise(resolve => resolve(responseHandler(result)))` can be written `Promise.resolve(responseHandler(result))`, and given that the function is already async you can just `return responseHandler(result)`. If you've having to write `as unknown as ...` you haven't *fixed* any problems.